# Python: How to multiply a column in a 3D array by a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures

I have a simple 3D numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[[0, 1]],
              [[2, 3]],
              [[4, 5]]])
```

How can I multiply the second column, by negative 1, to obtain:

```
np.array([[[0, -1]],
          [[2, -3]],
          [[4, -5]]])
```

I tried using

```
a[:,1] *= -1
```

However, I think this only works for 2D arrays.

Comment: So what happened instead? Multiplication works across any number of dimensions, not just 2D arrays.

Comment: Add another index for 2nd dimension. `np.array[:,:,1] *= -1`

Comment: @Psidom I receive this error when I add another :, so I'm not sure what my problem is 


    a = a[:,:,1] *= -1
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another `:` slice for the middle dimension:

```
a[:, :, 1] *= -1
# 1, 2, 3  dimensions
```

or use the [`...` ellipsis object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object) to skip all the dimensions but the last:

```
a[..., 1] *= -1
# ?  , last  dimensions.
```

You can also spell out the name of this object:

```
a[Ellipsis, 1] *= -1
```

See the [indexing documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> **Ellipsis** expands to the number of `:` objects needed for the selection tuple to index all dimensions.

Demo:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[[0, 1]],
   ...:               [[2, 3]],
   ...:               [[4, 5]]])

In [3]: a[..., 1] *= -1

In [4]: a
Out[4]:
array([[[ 0, -1]],

       [[ 2, -3]],

       [[ 4, -5]]])
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I figured I could just add another : slice, however, I run into another error saying invalid syntax, with an arrow pointing to the "="

Comment: a = a[:, :, 1] *= -1
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Drop the `a =`. You are **already** assigning with the `*=` augmented assignment.

Comment: OMG what worked was using ... as your first example